# .split returns NaN by converting string into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I need to convert a string, which contains several dates, into an array.
This works perfectly fine as long as the string contains of numbers. 
The string containing information on the dates looks as following:

```
 Wed Nov 01 2017 13:06:56 GMT+0100 (CET),Wed Nov 01 2017 13:07:10 GMT+0100 (CET),Wed Nov 01 2017 13:07:12 GMT+0100 (CET),Wed Nov 01 2017 13:07:13 GMT+0100 (CET),Wed Nov 01 2017 13:07:15 GMT+0100 (CET),Wed Nov 01 2017 13:07:16 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

My code looks as following:

```
var times = string.split(",").map(Number);
console.log(times[0]);
```

Unfortunately, this results in:

```
NaN
```

I cannot explain why it is not working. Even if I replace

```
","
```

by

```
"GMT+"
```

it is still not working. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: what do you want to accomplish by using .map(Number)?

Comment: I just want to be able to get access of the data of the array via times[0].

Comment: As @ObsidianAge mentioned that will give you access to the first string but if you want to convert them to dates you can use .map() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting the string is working as it should.

The problem is that by calling `.map(Number)`, you are trying to pass each element of the array to the Number constructor. This returns NaN, since the strings can't be converted directly into numbers.

For example:

```
new Number('Wed Nov 01 2017 13:06:56 GMT+0100 (CET)'); // NaN
```

What you probably want is `.map(Date.parse)`, since the Date.parse function can handle strings on this format. The result will be the "number representing the milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC" ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse))

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually **need** to use `map()` at all; simply using

```
 var times = string.split(",");
```

will give you the times split in the `times` array, which you can access with `times[0]`:

```js
var string = 'Wed Nov 01 2017 13:06:56 GMT+0100 (CET),Wed Nov 01 2017 13:07:10 GMT+0100 (CET),Wed Nov 01 2017 13:07:12 GMT+0100 (CET),Wed Nov 01 2017 13:07:13 GMT+0100 (CET),Wed Nov 01 2017 13:07:15 GMT+0100 (CET),Wed Nov 01 2017 13:07:16 GMT+0100 (CET)';
var times = string.split(",");
console.log(times[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need I guess:

**ES6**

```
let times = string.split(',').map(d => new Date(d));
```

**ES5**

```
var times = string.split(',').map(function (d) { return new Date(d)});
```